# JSON data in RecyclerView doesn't appear before Swipe Refresh and looping

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I am trying to use SwipeRefreshLayout to refresh data from JSON on recyclerview in fragment. I have try, but the result is data doesn't appear before Swipe Refresh and if I refresh the layout the data will be looping.

Here is my code :

**Fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private View myFragmentView;

    private String TAG = Tab1.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://sayangoppa.com/ibn/jadwal.php";

    List<jsonContent> listcontent=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Fragment1, container, false);

        //SwipeRefreshLayout begin
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(){
                new GetContacts().execute();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        return myFragmentView;
}
```

Comment: What part of your question consumers any JSON data? I see a URL, but no network operation

Comment: I am trying using SwipeRefreshLayout in fragment. But when first time app opened, data doesn't appear before I swipe refresh the layout. And when data already appear and I try to swipe refresh again, it's looping not refresh the data.

Comment: Your question is missing a [mcve]. The Asynctask code needs to be part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the result is data doesn't appear before Swipe Refresh

You never execute the Asynctask before the swipe...

For example

```
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener(){
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(){
            listcontent.clear(); // prevent repeating data 
            new GetContacts().execute();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    new GetContacts().execute();  // load before refresh 
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

> and if I refresh the layout the data will be looping.

You mean repeating? You need to call `listcontent.clear()` before you add new data

Comment: where I put that code ? Sorry, I am new in android developing.

Comment: You already have `return myFragmentView;` in your code. Add that one line above it

Comment: Thanks ! Works like a charm !